# Strapi how to start in background?

Tags: strapi

Usually we use "strapi start" to start strapi.

I'm hosting it on AWS ubuntu:

tried "start strapi &" to run it in background. However, once the terminal is closed, we can't access the strapi console anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Need to use pm2:

To Start:

```
npm install pm2 -g

NODE_ENV=production pm2 start server.js --name api
```

To list all process:

```
pm2 list
```

┌──────────┬────┬─────────┬──────┬───────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────┬────────────┬────────┬──────────┐

│ App name │ id │ version │ mode │ pid   │ status │ restart │ uptime │ cpu │ mem        │ user   │ watching │

├──────────┼────┼─────────┼──────┼───────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼─────┼────────────┼────────┼──────────┤

│ api      │ 0  │ 0.1.0   │ fork │ 21817 │ online │ 0       │ 2m     │ 0%  │ 108.0 MB   │ ubuntu │ disabled │

└──────────┴────┴─────────┴──────┴───────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────┴────────────┴────────┴──────────┘

To Stop, use the id:

```
pm2 stop 0
```

Comment: Script not found: server.js

Answer (score 10):

pm2 will be good for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2

I got `script not found: server.js` error when using @user1872384's solution.
So, here is the correct way to run strapi in background mode.

`NODE_ENV=production pm2 start --name APP_NAME npm -- start`

This will just tell pm2 to use `npm start` command and let npm do the `which script to run` part.

Hope it helps someone.

---

OR you can do this too:

`pm2 --name APP_NAME start "npm run develop"`
OR
`pm2 --name APP_NAME start "npm run start"`

Answer (score 9):

To run the strapi in development mode, use the following pm2 command from your project folder.

```
pm2 start npm --name my-project -- run develop
```

and

```
pm2 list
```

to view the status

Comment: Seems to be the only right answer for launching in devoplment mode.

Answer (score 6):

We also can start with pm2 by type

> pm2 start "yarn develop"

Comment: this is quick and dirty way to do it.. I love it! thanks for the tip1

Answer (score 3):

First

```
npm install pm2 -g
```

add server.js to root of your project and write below line:

```
const strapi = require('strapi');
strapi().start();
```

save then

```
pm2 start server.js
```

Comment: Thanks @Phonix it worked for me but how can I run the script in development env?

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean.

Comment: when I use above command it executed in production e.g. strapi start, but what if I want to run the strapi in dev mode: strapi develop

Comment: I've tried strapi().develop(); instead strapi().start(); but that not work

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use **pm2** and its **ecosystem.config.js** file.

1. Firstly, install pm2 by:

```sh
npm i -g pm2@latest
```

2. In **ecosystem.config.js**, add the following code:

```js
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'give-your-app-a-name',
      script: 'npm',
      args: 'start',
      watch: true, // automatically restart the server for file changes
      max_memory_restart: '450M',
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production',
      },
    },
    {
      name: 'give-your-another-app-a-name',
      script: 'npm',
      args: 'start',
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production',
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

3. Finally on your server do:

```sh
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the official page about [starting Strapi with PM2](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/guides/process-manager.html#starting-with-strapi-command).

**Starting with strapi command**

By default there is two important commands.

`yarn develop` to start your project in development mode.

`yarn start` to start your app for production.

You can also start your process manager using the yarn start or develop command.

```
pm2 start npm --name my-app -- run develop
```